# Conditional division in power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables, one has a column *gross profit* and the other has *total sales* and *category*. I want to divide *gross profit* by *total sales* where *category* = **SGA**.

How do I get there?

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables?

Comment: The dates of both tables are joined to a calendar dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create measure:

```
Gross Margin =
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE ( SUM ( Table1[Gross Profit] ), SUM ( Table2[Total Sales] ) ),
    Table2[Category] = "SGA"
)
```

Note: it will only work if you slice it by shared dimensions. If you run into issues, post your data model snapshot - DAX formulas are highly dependent on the model relations.

Comment: Na, this will do. Thanks.